# WebService Login with android not working

Tags: java, android, web-services, sql-server-2008, authentication

I'm trying to login to a webservice from android studio linked to SQLserver
here's my Webservice.java:

```
package comt.example.user.sql_login_test_2;


import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class WebService {


public static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Logins";

private  static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

private   static String URL = "http://localhost:3284/Service1.asmx"; 

public static boolean invokeLoginWS(String userName,String passWord, String webMethName) {

    boolean loginStatus = false;
    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
    // Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo unamePI = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo passPI = new PropertyInfo();
    // Set Username
    unamePI.setName("Login");
    // Set Value
    unamePI.setValue(userName);
    // Set dataType
    unamePI.setType(String.class);
    // Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(unamePI);
    //Set Password
    passPI.setName("UserPWD");
    //Set dataType
    passPI.setValue(passWord);
    //Set dataType
    passPI.setType(String.class);
    //Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(passPI);
    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object


    try {
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);
        // Get the response

        Object response = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to  boolean variable variable
        loginStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());/* HOW boolean from response to string ? */

    } catch (Exception e) {
    //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
    CheckLoginActivity.errored = true;
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Return booleam to calling object

    return loginStatus;
                                    }
}
```

and That's my Main.java :

```
package comt.example.user.sql_login_test_2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Main extends Activity { /*input here function */

public  static String OPERATION_NAME = "Logins"; /*hayde el Function Name*/

static boolean errored = false;
Button b;
TextView statusTV;
EditText userNameET , passWordET;
ProgressBar webservicePG;
String editTextUsername;
String editTextPassword;
boolean loginStatus;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    userNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    passWordET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    //Display Text control
    statusTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    //Button to trigger web service invocation
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //Display progress bar until web service invocation completes
    webservicePG = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    //Button Click Listener
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Check if text controls are not empty

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Waiting Please...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (userNameET.getText().length() != 0 && userNameET.getText().toString() != "") {
                if (passWordET.getText().length() != 0 && passWordET.getText().toString() != "") {
                    editTextUsername = userNameET.getText().toString();
                    editTextPassword = passWordET.getText().toString();
                    statusTV.setText("");
                    //Create instance for AsyncCallWS
                    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                    //Call execute
                    task.execute(editTextUsername,editTextPassword);


                }
                //If Password text control is empty
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "please enter your Passwrod??", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                //If Username text control is empty
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter Username??", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        }
    });

}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Call Web Method
        loginStatus = WebService.invokeLoginWS(editTextUsername,editTextPassword,OPERATION_NAME);


        //authenticateUser
        return loginStatus;
    }

    @Override
    //Once WebService returns response
    public void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        //Make Progress Bar invisible

        webservicePG.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Intent intObj = new Intent(Main.this,Home.class);

        //Error status is false
        if(!errored){
            //Based on Boolean value returned from WebService
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"still waiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(loginStatus){
                //Navigate to Home Screen
                startActivity(intObj);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "LOGIN SUCCESSFUL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                //Set Error message
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Login Failed, try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            //Error status is true
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error occured in invoking webservice", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        //Re-initialize Error Status to False

    }

    @Override
    //Make Progress Bar visible
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        webservicePG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

The app opens but always give me LoginFailed Please try again ....
the problem is probably the  loginStatus Boolean ... it's not changing ...when I set the initial as true, the app says LOGINSUCCESFULL but when the initial is false it doesn't ... I can't find what's wrong   :/